# Gem mail でマルチパートメールの本文が文字化けする

Tags: ruby

Railsの初心者です。 
現在製作しているアプリにメールの受信機能を実装したいです。 
Gem mailを用いてGmailの受信BOXのメールを取得してアプリケーション上で表示したいのですが、本文が文字化けしてしまいます。

・やりたいこと 
Ruby on railsのGem mailを用いて、Gmailの受信BOXのメールを取得してアプリケーション上で表示したい。subject(題目)と同じように、body(本文)も文字化けしないように表示したい。

・参考にしたページ
https://github.com/mikel/mail#readme
http://www.school.ctc-g.co.jp/columns/masuidrive/masuidrive07.html

・ブラウザの表示 
subject(題目)の表示例 
本日渋谷にて開催！！

body(本文)の表示例

```
-0-786876096-1455690672=:93410 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-2022-jp $BK\J8!"I=<($5$l$^$9$+!)(B --0-786876096-1455690672=:93410 Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-2022-jp <html><body><div style="color:; background-color:; font-family:MS PGothic, sans-serif;font-size:15pt"><div>$BK\J8!"I=<($5$l$^$9$+!)(B</div></div></body></html> --0-786876096-1455690672=:93410--
```

コントローラのソースコード 
【hoge_controller.rb】

```
class HogeController < ApplicationController

def inbox

require 'mail'

Mail.defaults do 
  retriever_method :pop3, { 
    :address => "pop.gmail.com", 
    :port => 995, 
    :user_name => 'hoge@gmail.com', 
    :password => 'パスワード', 
    :enable_ssl => true 
  } 
end

  @hoges = Mail.find(count: 5, order: :desc, what: :all)

end

end
```

ビューのソースコード 
【inbox.html.erb】

```
<% @hoges.each do |hoge| %>
<%= hoge.subject.encode('UTF-8') %>  # 正常に表示される 
<%= hoge.body.decoded.encode('UTF-8') %>  #**文字化けする**
<% end %>
```

・教えて頂きたいこと
body(本文)を文字化けさせずに表示させるやり方

何卒宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/27528

Answer (score 1, accepted):

本文がマルチパートで構成されていますので、たとえば最初のパートを対象とするのであれば以下のようにします。

```
hoge.parts.first.decoded
```

**参考**

マルチパートであるか判定する:

```
hoge.multipart?
```

`text/plain` であるパートを取り出す (無い場合にはnil):

```
hoge.parts.find { |part| part.content_type =~ /\Atext\/plain\b/i }
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！
hoge.parts.first.decoded、を実装して文字化けを修正できました。  
本当にありがとうございましたm(_ _)m